# Using a regular JavaScript library inside a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm curious what's the best way to use a regular JavaScript library (not written as a React component) inside a React environment.

For example, let's say there's a JavaScript library that embeds a simple widget to my webpage. The instructions are as follows:

1. Include the loading tag in the header.
2. Embed the snippet anywhere you want.

In a normal webpage, I would do the following:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://karaoke.com/source.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello look at my cool widget library</h1>
    <karaoke width="600" height="400" />
</body>
```

How do I achieve the same effect where I have a React component like this?

```
class MainView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>I want to show my karaoke widget here, but how?</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main purpose of JSX is to feel like HTML. The main purpose of `render` in a React component is to render that "fake" (virtual) HTML. If your external widget is also a React component, the solution is straightforward:

```
class MainView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello look at my cool widget library</h1>
        <Widget width="600" height="400" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

All you have to make sure is that the code above runs **after** your widget script is loaded (so the `Widget` component is present). The exact solution to this would depend on your build system.

If your external library is not a React component, then you cannot use a custom `widget` tag and you must render actual HTML.

The big trick is to not return from `render` but manually render ourselves after the widget initializes what it needs:

```
class MainView extends Component {
  render() {
    // don't render anything
    return <div/>;
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    // find the DOM node for this component
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

    // widget does stuff
    $(node).activateMyCoolWidget();

    // start a new React render tree with widget node
    ReactDOM.render(<div>{this.props.children}</div>, node);
  }
});
```

Take a look at [portals](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md) for more details.

Comment: Does react support any kind of element tag as long as it's loaded?

Comment: @MaximusS it supports any HTML tag or a React component.

Comment: That's where I got confused. If an external library called maximus.js provided a widget named maximus, would React understand <maximus width="600" />?

Comment: By "widget" do you mean a React Component?

Comment: No widget is just a random library name that I thought of. My question is about using a conventional js library that is not written as a React component. For example, how would you use Google Maps api inside React component? Why is there a React Google Maps Wrapper?

Comment: That link at the end is gold

Comment: One followup question: what if the external library requires you to embed their custom element tag in the DOM for it to load?